# JBOSS EAP 7.1 connect to oracle 12c database

Tags: java, oracle, jboss

I have installed JBOSS EAP 7.1 to my server and is able to connect to a remote oracle 12c database with instant oracle client.

However, I fail to connect database using JBOSS datasource.

in my $(JBOSS_HOME)/domain/configuration/doamin.xml
I have define a driver

```
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="oracle" module="oracle.jdbc">
                        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

and I have define datasource:

```
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/TMISDS" pool-name="TMISDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.65.13.167:1521:TMISDEV</connection-url>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>TMIS</user-name>
                        <password>myPW</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

I also check the $(JBOSS_HOME)/modules/com/oracle/main/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="oracle.jdbc">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc7.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="ucp.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

I have restart the server serveral times with following logging:

```
    =========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0

  JAVA: java

  JAVA_OPTS: -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

11:25:00,925 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.6.0.Final-redhat-1
11:25:01,328 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Host Controller.status] (main) WFLYPC0018: Starting process 'Host Controller'
[Host Controller] 11:25:02,070 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.6.0.Final-redhat-1
[Host Controller] 11:25:02,361 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.7.SP1-redhat-1
[Host Controller] 11:25:02,426 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1) starting
[Host Controller] 11:25:03,302 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/host=master/core-service=management/management-interface=native-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
[Host Controller] 11:25:03,304 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/host=master/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
[Host Controller] 11:25:03,373 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (Controller Boot Thread) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.1.7.Final-redhat-1
[Host Controller] 11:25:03,418 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYHC0003: Creating http management service using network interface (management) port (9990) securePort (-1)
[Host Controller] 11:25:03,438 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO version 3.5.4.Final-redhat-1
[Host Controller] 11:25:03,451 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.5.4.Final-redhat-1
[Host Controller] 11:25:03,581 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.5.Final-redhat-1
[Host Controller] 11:25:03,602 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYPAT0050: JBoss EAP cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
[Host Controller] 11:25:03,630 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
[Host Controller] 11:25:03,719 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYRMT0001: Listening on 10.65.161.52:9999
[Host Controller] 11:25:05,171 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/profile=default/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
[Host Controller] 11:25:05,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/profile=ha/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
[Host Controller] 11:25:05,333 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/profile=full/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
[Host Controller] 11:25:05,405 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/profile=full-ha/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
[Host Controller] 11:25:05,775 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYHC0023: Starting server server-one
11:25:05,826 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Server:server-one.status] (ProcessController-threads - 3) WFLYPC0018: Starting process 'Server:server-one'
[Host Controller] 11:25:07,381 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (management task-4) WFLYHC0021: Server [Server:server-one] connected using connection [Channel ID 32d0a86c (inbound) of Remoting connection 67c39bd8 to 10.65.161.52/10.65.161.52:37481 of endpoint "master:MANAGEMENT" <63e25a25>]
[Host Controller] 11:25:07,434 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYHC0023: Starting server server-two
[Host Controller] 11:25:07,450 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (server-registration-threads - 1) WFLYHC0020: Registering server server-one
11:25:07,482 INFO  [org.jboss.as.process.Server:server-two.status] (ProcessController-threads - 3) WFLYPC0018: Starting process 'Server:server-two'
[Host Controller] 11:25:11,449 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (management task-8) WFLYHC0021: Server [Server:server-two] connected using connection [Channel ID 27ace650 (inbound) of Remoting connection 5ff8b08f to 10.65.161.52/10.65.161.52:48725 of endpoint "master:MANAGEMENT" <63e25a25>]
[Host Controller] 11:25:11,528 INFO  [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (server-registration-threads - 1) WFLYHC0020: Registering server server-two
[Host Controller] 11:25:11,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0062: Http management interface listening on http://10.65.161.52:9990/management and https://10.65.161.52:-1/management
[Host Controller] 11:25:11,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0053: Admin console listening on http://10.65.161.52:9990 and https://10.65.161.52:-1
[Host Controller] 11:25:11,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1) (Host Controller) started in 10071ms - Started 77 of 79 services (23 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Anyone point the way to me? I am new to JBOSS setup, hope the information was relevant.

Thanks!

**Addidtional information from server.log**

```
[Server:server-one] = 
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
    file.encoding = UTF-8
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = /
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.headless = true
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.print.PSPrinterJob
    java.class.path = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext
    java.home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
    java.library.path = /root/instantclient_12_1/:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
    java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
    java.runtime.name = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_102-b14
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_102
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.102-b14
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
    javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
    jboss.bind.address.management = 10.65.161.52
    jboss.domain.base.dir = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain
    jboss.domain.config.dir = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/configuration
    jboss.home.dir = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0
    jboss.host.name = localhost
    jboss.modules.dir = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/modules
    jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
    jboss.node.name = master:server-one
    jboss.qualified.host.name = localhost.localdomain
    jboss.server.base.dir = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one
    jboss.server.config.dir = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/data
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/data/content
    jboss.server.log.dir = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/log
    jboss.server.name = server-one
    jboss.server.persist.config = true
    jboss.server.temp.dir = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/tmp
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:/u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/data/logging.properties
    module.path = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/modules
    org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
    org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Linux
    os.version = 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
    path.separator = :
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/classes
    sun.boot.library.path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.102-4.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = 
    sun.desktop = gnome
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/jboss-modules.jar -mp /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/modules org.jboss.as.server
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = unknown
    user.country = US
    user.dir = /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0
    user.home = /root
    user.language = en
    user.name = root
    user.timezone = Asia/Hong_Kong
2018-05-28 16:07:44,841 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) VM Arguments: -D[Server:server-one] -Xms1000m -Xmx1000m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.bind.address.management=10.65.161.52 -Djboss.home.dir=/u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.log.dir=/u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/log -Djboss.server.temp.dir=/u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/tmp -Djboss.server.data.dir=/u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/data -Dlogging.configuration=file:/u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/data/logging.properties 
2018-05-28 16:07:44,904 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO version 3.5.4.Final-redhat-1
2018-05-28 16:07:44,911 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.5.4.Final-redhat-1
2018-05-28 16:07:44,951 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.5.Final-redhat-1
2018-05-28 16:07:45,226 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 2) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.1.7.Final-redhat-1
2018-05-28 16:07:47,181 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2018-05-28 16:07:47,542 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
2018-05-28 16:07:47,594 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
2018-05-28 16:07:47,633 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
2018-05-28 16:07:47,635 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.2.Final-redhat-1
2018-05-28 16:07:47,669 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.18.Final-redhat-2 starting
2018-05-28 16:07:47,674 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
2018-05-28 16:07:47,762 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
2018-05-28 16:07:47,839 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
2018-05-28 16:07:47,840 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
2018-05-28 16:07:47,892 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
2018-05-28 16:07:48,142 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.0.24.Final-redhat-1
2018-05-28 16:07:48,153 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 4 core threads with 32 task threads based on your 2 available processors
2018-05-28 16:07:48,165 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYIIOP0001: Activating IIOP Subsystem
2018-05-28 16:07:48,187 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
2018-05-28 16:07:48,355 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.6.Final-redhat-1)
2018-05-28 16:07:48,476 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
2018-05-28 16:07:48,496 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
2018-05-28 16:07:48,630 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
2018-05-28 16:07:48,731 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
2018-05-28 16:07:48,797 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 12.1)
2018-05-28 16:07:48,811 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 0.0.0.0:8080
2018-05-28 16:07:48,879 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = oracle
2018-05-28 16:07:49,064 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
2018-05-28 16:07:49,065 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 8 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
2018-05-28 16:07:49,009 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
2018-05-28 16:07:49,675 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYDM0111: Keystore /u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/configuration/application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
2018-05-28 16:07:49,794 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYPAT0050: JBoss EAP cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
2018-05-28 16:07:50,010 INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYIIOP0009: CORBA ORB Service started
2018-05-28 16:07:50,065 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 0.0.0.0:8443
2018-05-28 16:07:50,124 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2018-05-28 16:07:50,203 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=/u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/data/activemq/journal,bindingsDirectory=/u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/data/activemq/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=/u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/data/activemq/largemessages,pagingDirectory=/u01/var/jboss-eap-7.1.0/domain/servers/server-one/data/activemq/paging)
2018-05-28 16:07:50,301 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.9.Final-redhat-1 (Apache CXF 3.1.12.redhat-1) 
2018-05-28 16:07:50,333 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
2018-05-28 16:07:50,456 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2018-05-28 16:07:50,457 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2018-05-28 16:07:51,051 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
2018-05-28 16:07:51,052 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
2018-05-28 16:07:51,052 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
2018-05-28 16:07:51,052 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
2018-05-28 16:07:51,163 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) AMQ221007: Server is now live
2018-05-28 16:07:51,163 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 1.5.5.008-redhat-1 [default, nodeID=9ccd390e-599e-11e8-b113-0050568a15ce] 
2018-05-28 16:07:51,173 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) AMQ221003: Deploying queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
2018-05-28 16:07:51,227 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) AMQ221003: Deploying queue jms.queue.DLQ
2018-05-28 16:07:51,295 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) AMQ122005: Invalid "host" value "0.0.0.0" detected for "http-connector" connector. Switching to "localhost". If this new address is incorrect please manually configure the connector to use the proper one.
2018-05-28 16:07:51,330 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
2018-05-28 16:07:51,357 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
2018-05-28 16:07:51,365 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
2018-05-28 16:07:51,399 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-1) Resource adaptor started
2018-05-28 16:07:51,399 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-1) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
2018-05-28 16:07:51,400 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
2018-05-28 16:07:51,400 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
2018-05-28 16:07:51,579 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2018-05-28 16:07:51,589 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.10.Final-redhat-1) started in 7578ms - Started 327 of 640 services (418 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: "However, I fail to connect database using JBOSS datasource." => And what error do you get?

Comment: Failed to create JDBC connection.
There are no running servers bound to this datasource.

Comment: Please post the _whole_ stacktrace!

Comment: sorry I am new to JBOSS, would you mind telling me how to find the stacktrace?!

Comment: Well ... Where do you see the "Failed to create JDBC connection" error?

Comment: from web admin console.

Comment: I guess, you have a full stacktrace in server.log.

Comment: thanks, edit my post above, but I can only see ExampleDS in datasource, which is an sample datasource. My datasource should be TMISDS but I dont know why no related information in the log

Comment: Sorry, it seems I can't help you. Maybe because you want to define a XA datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that's the domain configuration in which you declared the datasource is the one deployed ?

If your server is part of a domain, it may be managed by a [domain controller](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-StandaloneServer) which provides its configuration, otherwise you may want to run your server as a standalone one and in this case the datasource must be configured in standalone.xml and the server started using standalone.sh.

Comment: thanks! I can connect to datasource now using standalone.sh to start JBOSS